# Modificar consulta MYSQL para mostrar mensaje en caso de no encontrar datos

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Como puedo modificar esta consulta para que si no encuentra resultados de un demo_id en la tabla tags en lugar de no mostrar el demo en la respuesta que en donde deberian ir los tags dijera algo como `no category`.

Consulta

```
SELECT `i`.`name`, `i`.`id`, `i`.`img`, `d`.`url`, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ', ') as tags FROM `demos` i INNER JOIN `details` d ON `i`.`id` = `d`.`demo_id`  INNER JOIN tags t ON t.demo_id = i.id  GROUP BY `i`.`id` ORDER BY `i`.`created_at` ASC
```

Respuesta

```js
{
    "name": "4",
    "id": "beqvok",
    "img": "https://xx-xx.s3.amazonaws.com/demos/1491416271916",
    "url": "http://xxx/cms/demos",
    "tags": "ReactJS, NodeJS"
  }
```

Como puedo hacer para que si elimino ReactJS y NodeJS que tienen la id `beqvok` en el caso de ese demo en lugar de no mostrarse mas me muestre algo asi

```js
{
    "name": "4",
    "id": "beqvok",
    "img": "https://xx-xx.s3.amazonaws.com/demos/1491416271916",
    "url": "xxx/cms/demos",
    "tags": "No Category"
  }
```

Comment: Podrías dar de alta una categoría que se llame "sin categoría" y colocar por default si no encuentra ninguna?

Comment: Mhm, no. Digamos que no es lo mas optimo para mi caso

Answer (score 0):

pruebe con esto

```
SELECT
  `i`.`name`,
  `i`.`id`,
  `i`.`img`,
  `d`.`url`,
  IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ',"no category"), ') AS tags
FROM `demos` i
  INNER JOIN `details` d
    ON `i`.`id` = `d`.`demo_id`
  FULL OUTER JOIN tags t
    ON t.demo_id = i.id
GROUP BY `i`.`id`
ORDER BY `i`.`created_at`
  ASC
```

o con...

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN en vez de FULL OUTER JOIN
```

Comment: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `demos` i INNER JOIN `details` d ON `i`.`id` = `d`.`demo_id` FULL OUTER JOI' at line 1